# PHP/MySQL Can't print column generated by query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a "top 15" results based on a field called UID, works great except not printing the count column in PHP, it does in PHPMyAdmin though.

```
SELECT * , COUNT( UID ) AS Count
FROM UserReports
GROUP BY  `UID` 
ORDER BY Count DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

Here's the Returning Array:

```
( [ID] => 18 [Date] => 2016-05-28 13:58:05 [Name] => a [UID] => a [Reason] => a [Staff] => Patrick [Count] => 2 ) 

( [ID] => 19 [Date] => 2016-05-28 13:58:07 [Name] => b [UID] => b [Reason] => b [Staff] => Patrick [Count] => 1 )
```

PHP Code:

```
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['UID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Count'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 print_r($row);
echo "<br>";

    }
```

But the output doesn't show the count column for me and I can't quite work out why.

[Missing Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43lkX.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's your HTML. You have 6 columns in the screenshot, but only 5 in your loop. Look at your own screenshot; you have 2 and 1 in there. Look at your HTML source also.

Comment: Thanks, completely overlooked that there!

Comment: You're welcome Patrick. Solved or not? Just curious and if it should be posted as the solution to the question.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer  then, seeing answers were given yet I was the one who did in fact spot that.

Comment: Thanks, will mark it as so in a min!

Comment: You're welcome Patrick, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment to answer, seeing it was the real problem.

You have 6 columns in the screenshot, but only 5 `<td>`'s in your loop. Look at your own screenshot; you have 2 and 1 counts in there. Look at your HTML source also; it is also a "tool".

What's happening here is that the iterated values have been shifted.

You will need to match them.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `select *` with `group by`.  This is a (mis)feature in MySQL that is supported neither by the standard nor by other databases.

Instead, focus on the columns of interest:

```
SELECT UID, COUNT( UID ) AS Count
FROM UserReports
GROUP BY  `UID` 
ORDER BY Count DESC 
LIMIT 15;
```

If you want other columns, such as `NAME`, either wrap them in aggregation functions (`MAX(NAME)`) or include them in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Have a look at a comment I left under the question. I think it may be relevant. Edit: seems I was right given his response to it.